# Webpack, figuring out where to register Handlebar helpers to my project

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, handlebars.js

I have an annoying problem which is bothering me because I'm not used to work with Handlebars templating system.

I forked a project off git (https://github.com/SimonDEvans/design-boilerplate) which included basic Handlebars integration. In the README it states that the project support **Handlebars helpers.**

However the documentation is lacking and I can't find **WHERE** I even put Handlebar helper functions in so that I can use them in my templating files.

So I turn to SO to see if any of you guys have worked with similar setups using the `handlebars-loader` NPM

Here is a snippet of the Webpack config file that runs the handlebars node

```
function getLoaders() {
  const loaders = [
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'handlebars-loader',
    },
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'tests'),
      ],
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: 'babel',
    },
  ];

  return loaders;
}
```

I will be forever grateful to whoever can give me any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register handlebars helpers, apparently [here](https://github.com/SimonDEvans/design-boilerplate/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L72).

Comment: Thanks for looking into that, I looked in the gulpfile, but had previously been unable to use them the helpers for whatever reason. Happy thats sorted out! Thank you!